# Writing the solution of a linear first order DE in the way that the null solution and the particular solutions are separated

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that via the integrator factor one can write the solution of a linear first order DE as:

$$y(x) = \frac{\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx +  A}{e^{\int p(x) dx}}$$

I was wondering how could this expression be rearranged to the terms from the null and particular solutions be separated. I came with this solution

\begin{align*}
y(x) &= \frac{\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx +  A}{e^{\int p(x) dx}} \nonumber\\
     &= e^{-\int_0^x p(t) dt} \int e^{\int_0^x p(t) dt}q(x)dx +  Ae^{-\int_0^x p(t) dt} \\
     &= e^{-\int_0^x p(t) dt} \int_0^x e^{\int_0^s p(t) dt}q(s)ds +  Ae^{-\int_0^x p(t) dt} \\
     &= \int_0^x e^{\int_0^s p(t) dt -\int_0^x p(t) dt}q(s)ds +  Ae^{-\int_0^x p(t) dt}.    
\end{align*}

Is this a valid expression?

Answer (score 1):

Your second to last equation is correct. Your last equation is false.

There is no need for much calculus :
$$y(x) = \frac{\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx +  A}{e^{\int p(x) dx}}=
\frac{\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx}{e^{\int p(x) dx}}+A \frac{ 1}{e^{\int p(x) dx}}$$
$\begin{cases}
\frac{\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx}{e^{\int p(x) dx}}=e^{-\int p(x) dx}\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x)dx \quad \text{is a particular solution.}\\
\frac{ 1}{e^{\int p(x) dx}} =e^{-\int p(x) dx} \quad \text{is the solution of the homogeneous equation.} \end{cases}$

Comment: Great, but I think the solutions are with their names changed, no?

Comment: Of course. Typo corrected.